# An API version is required, but was not specified. webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing, api-versioning

```
var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
{
    ConstraintMap =
    {
        ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint )
    }
};
                
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
config.AddApiVersioning(o => o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true);


[ApiVersion("2.05")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/ger")]
public class caGerController
[Route("~/api/ger/getDetail")]
[Route("getDetail")]
 GetGerData


[ApiVersion("1")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/gerDetail")]

public class caGerDetailsController
caGerController
[Route("~/api/gerDetail/getDetail")]
[Route("getDetail")]
 GetGerData
   
>>  GetGerData
```

Result:

1. Both URL working with v1 version ROUTE.
2. Second URL working for both, v1 and direct without v1 route as well i.e. [Route("~/api/gerDetail/getDetail")]
3. PROBLEM: first URL is only working with v1 and its not working with direct route like " [Route("~/api/ger/getDetail")]"
   and getting an error as below:

   "Error": {
   "Code": "ApiVersionUnspecified",
   "Message": "An API version is required, but was not specified."
   }

How to solve this issue?
When I change from 2.05 to 1.0 then it works but 2.0 or 2.05 both do not work. Is there a separate folder required?

Answer (score 14):

The **ApiVersionUnspecified** happens because **all** routes require an explicit API version by default. You opt out of this behavior using:

```
options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true
```

This setting means that a default API version is assumed when a client doesn't provide one. The default value is:

```
options.DefaultApiVersion // equals 1.0 by default
```

When you use the URL segment versioning method, you can't have two different controllers that both an *unversioned* route. The route without an API version can only map to a single controller. Since the default is "1.0" and you have a controller with the *unversioned* route, that's the one that will always been matched.

Comment: How do you specify a version?

Comment: _How_ you specify an API version depends on the style of versioning you are using. In the original question, the URL segment method is being used. This means that the request specifies the API version in the form of `api/v1/ger`. Using this style of versioning, if you want a _default_ version, then you'll need a second route for it (e.g. `api/ger`). With both routes and `options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true` set, the routes `api/v1/ger` and `api/ger` with both go to the same implementation.

Answer (score 3):

By adding API versioning, the default behavior is that it uses QueryString versioning.

```
   config.AddApiVersioning(cfg => {});
```

api-version=1.0

To specify a version, you can add the querystring parameter **api-version=1.0** at the end.

Example:

http://localhost:6600/api/test?api-version=1.0

You can change the version like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
      GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
...

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
       ...
      config.AddApiVersioning(cfg =>
      {
         cfg.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1,1);
      });
```

So you can change the version like this:

http://localhost:6600/api/test?api-version=1.1

By adding **AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified**, you don't have to specify a version.

```
  config.AddApiVersioning(cfg =>
  {
     cfg.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1,1);
     cfg.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
  });
```

This will work:
http://localhost:6600/api/test

You can also add **ReportApiVersions**

```
  config.AddApiVersioning(cfg =>
  {
     cfg.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1,1);
     cfg.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
     cfg.ReportApiVersions = true;
  });
```

The response will have a new header **api-supported-versions** which specifies what versions are supported for the call they made.